# Positively invariant $(S,I)$-triangle for SIS dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, set-invariance

Consider the following differential equations

$${dS \over dt} = \lambda-\beta SI-\mu S+\theta I$$

$${dI \over dt} =\beta SI-(\mu +d)I-\theta I$$

In all papers that I have read it is only mentioned that

$$\Omega = \left\{ (S,I) : I\geq 0, S \geq 0, S+I \leq {\lambda \over \mu} \right\}$$

is positively invariant. How can I explicitly show that the set $\Omega $ is positively invariant?

Comment: Did you get something from the answer below?

Comment: @ Did Hmm not really....but i was able to show and understand it it differently. Actually i had to do it for another model but posted this one for help.

Comment: And... in such situations, you simply stay silent and avoid to interact with the OP?

Comment: Sorry , i do not understand what u are trying to mean . I do not post question often and not much familiar.

Comment: Apparently you did understand what I was saying, a few seconds after having posted a comment declaring otherwise. Good.

Comment: truly, i was not being impolite at all and i did even try to understand what u were saying (without certainty of what you meant), i don't know what big mistake i have done ,that you got so irritated..sorry if you thought that i was being rude which was not the case.

Comment: "so irritated"? Sorry, but no (at the most, vaguely amused by some bad manners one can see on display on this site).

Comment: you are still thinking that i was being ill-mannered, but my intention was not bad at all, maybe the structure of my sentences looks as if i was rude. Your responds are so weird to me. And when i said "sorry" ,i sincerely meant it, it was not sarcastic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boundary of the set (which is a triangle in the $(S,I)$-plane) consists of three line segments:
\begin{align}
 \ell_1 &= \left\{ (S,I) \,\middle\vert\, I = 0 ,\, 0 < S < \frac{\lambda}{\mu} \right\},\\
 \ell_2 &= \left\{ (S,I) \,\middle\vert\, 0 < I < \frac{\lambda}{\mu},\, S = 0 \right\},\\
 \ell_3 &= \left\{ (S,I) \,\middle\vert\, S + I = \frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right\}.
\end{align}
A set is positive invariant if you can't escape it, i.e. if you start in the set, you stay in that set for all positive time. Now, the only way to escape such a set is to flow out of it -- at the boundaries! Therefore, the only thing you have to prove is that the flow at the boundaries of the set doesn't point out of the set at any point on the boundary. Pointing inwards everywhere is of course sufficient, but it's ok if the flow is tangential to the boundary; only if there is outwards pointing flow, the set isn't positive invariant anymore.